# Faster way to find the minium distance between words in an array

Tags: php, arrays

Consider I have this array:

```
$array = array(

'word1',
'abc',
'abc',
'word2',
 [other words]
'word1',
'dfg'
'word2',
 [other words]
);
```

I need to find the minimum distance between 2 given words. (let 'word1' and 'word2' be these 2 words)

In this case the minium distance between `word1` and `word2` is 1 because in the second group of words they are separated by only 'dfg'.

I wrote a simple code but it's too expsensive and I am looking for a faster version.

```
//> PSEUDO CODE
function minDistance( $words, $word1, $word2 ) {
    foreach( $words as $k=>$v) 
      if ( $v == $words1 )
         $positionsOfFirstWord[] = $k;

      if ( $v == $words2 )
         $positionsOfSecondWord[] = $k;


     //> If word1 or word2 was not found in the array then
     //> return max distance possibile (count($words))

     //> Now we have 2 array containg the position of both word we need.

     foreach( $positionsOfFirstWord as $v )
        foreach( $positionsOfSecondWord as $vv )
          $distance = abs($vv-$v);

}
```

Note the order of words in $array isn't important (that's why there is abs())

Do you think there could be a better version?

**Please note** the function must return 1 in this case too:

```
array(
 [other words]
'word2',
'dfg',
'word1'
 [other words]
);
```

Comment: Will an equal number of `word1` and `word2` always exist in `$array` or will there be occurrences where the number of each differs? Also, should reverse orders be counted? I.e. your example shows word2 immediately followed by word1, which is 0 distance.

Comment: @Ben: i don't have example where word2 is immedialy followed by word1. And let's not think when word1 and word2 aren't in the exact number of occurences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a simple loop is enough. Keep track over the current minimum and of the `last word1` and update current minimum if a `word2` is found.  Basically you are utilizing the fact that a `word2` will always be closest to the last `word1` found

```
 let minimum = INFINITY
 let lastword1 = -1
 let lastword2 =  -1
 foreach word w in words
 {

      if ( w is word1 )
      {
           lastword1 = current position;

           find distance between lastword2 and w update minimum if needed
      }

      if ( w is word2 )
      {
          lastword2 = current position;

          find distance between lastword1 and w update minimum if needed
      }

 }
```

You can do this in `O(n)` but there might faster ways if pre processing can be done and you need to answer multiple queries

Comment: I don't think this can work becasue the order of word1 and word2 found in the array isn't important. IE `array('word2','dfg','word1')` must return 1 anyway as minimun distance. Anyway if you can provide a simple pseudocde i can test it

Comment: You can easily adapt the above code to keep track of `w1 w2` minimum and `w2 w1` minimum . The minimum of these two is what you are looking for again in O(n)

Comment: I have added a second array as example, your code with taht array wouldn't work because word2 is found for first. (Especially the `find distance between lastword1 and w` can't work)

Comment: I think this works, I have added an answer with the real php code

Comment: i ran some test, it seems this version of code runs slower, dunno why.

Comment: Try a large list solely consisting of w1 and w2. Your original solution will be considerably slower. It is `O(n*n)` in worst case

Comment: generally the list of words only contains pretty few occurences of w1 and w2

Answer (score 1):

construct an array of ints as follows

1. iterate over array of words from top to bottom
2. if you encounter 'word1' and the last word encountered was not 'word1' then append the position to the array being constructed
3. if you encounter 'word2' and the last word encountered was not 'word2' then append the position to the array being constructed
4. if you encounter 'word2' and the last word encountered was 'word2' then update the last element of the array to the current position

now scan the array to find the minimum difference between any two pairs

repeat this process one more time except do step 4. with 'word1' instead of 'word2'

your answer is the smaller of the two minimums

Comment: (naturally you can optimize by fusing the 3 loops and avoiding constructing the arrays themselves -- the above is just an aid to thinking and to give an intuition into its correctness)

Answer (score 0):

why set up an array for the positions? Why not just save them as values and then do absolute value of the difference?

```
function distance($words, $first, $second) {

  $result = new Array();

  for(i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
    if($words[i] == $first) {
      $firstPos = i;
    } elseif($words[i] == $second) {
      $secondPos = i;
      $result[] = (abs($firstPos - $secondPos));
    }
  }

  // Find the smallest number in the result array
  $min = $result[0];
  for(i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
    if(result[i] < $min) {
      $min = result[i];
    }
  }

  return $min;

}
```

Comment: hi, i have added another array as example, your code with that array wouldn't work

Comment: Consider this array: http://codepad.org/OqcIttDD your func would return 3, instead of 1

Comment: @Vigrond: no, the word distance with that array is 3 even if the words are equal

Comment: Hmmm I misread the question, didn't realise you needed the minimum distance in case they occured more than once. Try the newest update. I'm rusty on php syntax since I've been doing Java recently so there might be a couple problems with syntax but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on parapura I wrote this, Dunno why but it seems it's working SLOWER

```
function minDistance2($words,$key1,$key2) {

    if ($key1 == $key2)
        return 0;

    $min = false;
    $p1 = false;
    $p2 = false;

    foreach($words as $k=>$v) {
        $calc = false;

        if ($v == $key1) {
            $p1 = $k;       
            $calc = true;
        } else if ($v == $key2) {
            $p2 = $k;
            $calc = true;
        }

        if ($calc) {
            if ($p1===false || $p2===false)
                continue;

            $d = abs($p1-$p2) - 1;

            if ($min === false || $d<$min )
                $min = $d;
        }

        if ($min!==false && $min<=0)
            return 0;
    }

    return ($min===false ? 0 : $min);
}
```